# Mixing Two String Recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this strings : "case" and "ro". I need to get every combination between them, where I substitute the single letters from the second string into the first one, but only if the letter is greater than the other one. Ex:  in "rose : r>c, o>a.  Other Examples are: "cose", "roso", "coso"
I tried writing something, using iteration, but it goes on a infinite loop and doesn't generate nothing. If someone can help me figure out a simpler way to do this, it would be great.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please provide your code, and any errors you've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering on basis of what i have understood from the question. Please check whether the following answer is correct for you.If yes then I can explain the code later.

```
def solve( s1, s2):  # prints all combinations of s1 from letters of s2 in a list
            ans = [s1]   
            if s1=="":
                return ans
            tmp = solve( s1[1:],s2 )  
            ans += [ s1[0]+x for x in tmp ]
            for c in s2:
                if c>s1[0]:
                    ans += [ c+x for x in tmp ]
            return list(set(ans))

print solve("case","ro")
```

Comment: Yes! Oh now i got where i was wrong! Thanks! I basically messed up the iteration... what a shame

Comment: cool i think these kind of question are well suited for recursion, not iteration